# What is Poetry? What does not count as Poetry?

Tags: meaning, etymology, poetry, literature, poetic

**Background:**

a google "[define:poem](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=definition:%20diction&oq=definition:%20diction&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3033j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)" did not give me much closure:

> poem: a piece of writing in which the expression of feelings and ideas
>   is given intensity by particular attention to diction (sometimes
>   involving rhyme), rhythm, and imagery.

The deinition feels too vague I mean even this post could count as a poem then surely. I thought perhaps instead of a definition I could get more of a intuition by watching and reading several commentaries and critiques of Sylvia Plath's poems... but I am left with more questions than answers and I am not even sure what I heard yesterday was a poem anymore.

**Questions:**

- What is a poem?
- When it (whatever it is) does not rhyme how do I **know** it is a poem?
- If I write my thoughts onto a page is that a poem?
- If so then why call them poems? Why give them such a fancy name, why not just call them artistic thoughts?

Comment: This may be a question for the writer's site here. There are many different thoughts/opinions about what can be called a poem as opposed to prose. Structure/meter/metaphore matters; see haiku. Wiki has a good article on it.

Comment: A poem is called a poem because it is a 'made thing': created by drawing upon all the resources of the poetic tradition to shape an inexhaustibly interpretable statement of truth. You know it is a poem because it goes through you like a spear.

Comment: Thank you both for those comments. If it is down to opinion then I suppose I should stop worrying so much and just help me define it for myself without feeling so worried im "getting it wrong", so cheers for that. I also found this, which is quite interesting, apparently it is possible to have one letter poems, and they do not even have to be real letters! http://peopleofar.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/worlds-shortest-poem/

Comment: Interesting link! It reminds me of [shape poetry](http://www.shadowpoetry.com/resources/wip/shape.html) and other forms. While I like yours better, I find the greats hard to beat: Frost, Burns, Dickinson, Donne, Browning, Neruda, Cummings, and so many more. I like @StoneyB's description.

Comment: What is a poem?

That's an unknown

Or maybe a unknown known

But I bet I'd figure it out

If only I was shown.

Comment: To add to the confusion, even this is a poem (a german one, though): http://www.libica.org/salon/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fisches-nachtgesang.jpg Its the lullaby of a fish...

Comment: What is art?  Poetry is simply art in word form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 111a of *Even Cowgirls Get the Blues*, by Tom Robbins:

> Poetry is nothing more than an intensification or illumination of common objects and everyday events, until they shine with their singular nature, until we can experience their power, until we can follow their steps in the dance, until we can discern what parts they play in the Great Order of Love.
>   How is this done? By fucking around with syntax.
>
> Definitions are limiting.
>   Limitations are deadening.
>   To limit oneself is a kind of suicide.
>   To limit another is a kind of murder.
>   To limit poetry is a Hiroshima of the human spirit.
>
> Danger! Radiation!
>   Unauthorized Personnel Not Allowed on the premises of Chapter 111a.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler this chimes so well with my current interpretation of it (albeit from only two days of intense reading around). Now I'm actually starting to think of poetry as a really neat tool to go out and learn and understand things that I might be curious about, from insects to love - but rather than the rushed and in-human tools we have these days (textbooks, google) poetry would help me learn about things from an emotional and more human perspective thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Poetry is art, your words are the colors and the page is your canvas.  We experience good poetry the same way as we experience good art.  It sweeps us away to a world that is more vivid and more real that the one we am currently stand in.  How this is done is one of the great mysteries of life.  That it is done, is a gift.